# $T\setminus\{p\}$ and $S^1\wedge S^1$ are smoothly homotopically equivalent: rigorous proof

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

Let $T=S^1\times S^1$. I want to prove that $M:= T\setminus\{p\}$ and $N:=S^1\wedge S^1$ are smoothly homotopically equivalent.

I Just know the following facts:

- M and N are $C^0$-homotopically equivalent: let $r: \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \partial([-1,1]^2)=:B$ the map
  $r(x):=\frac{x}{||x||_\infty}$
  where $||x||:=\max\{x_1,x_2\}$ where $x=(x_1,x_2)$. Clearly $r_{|B}=id_B$. The map $r$ induces a map $\rho: T\setminus\{p\}\to B /\sim$ where $\sim$ is the usual equivalence relation that defines the torus. Let $π:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to T\setminus\{p\}$ the canonical projection onto the quotient (here $p$ is the equivalence class of $(0,0)$.
- Two smooth manifolds are $C^0$-homotopically equivalent if and only if they are smoothly homotopically equivalent.

**BUT** I don't want to use this last fact. My questions are

- a) $r$ is a smooth map? If yes, does this implies that also $\rho$ is smooth?
- b) $\rho$ is a smooth homotopic equivalence? Is It true that $i_{π(B)}\circ \rho$ is $C^\infty$-homotopic to $id_{T\setminus\{p\}}$?

Comment: We don’t have two smooth manifolds, so good thing you don’t want to use “this last fact.”

Comment: Oh you're right :( thank you!

Comment: I am still puzzled by the meaning of smooth homotopy when $N$ is not a submanifold. The *radial* retraction of the square minus its center to its boundary is smooth as a map to its image in $\Bbb R^2$. I'm not sure why you're messing with $r$, which is not smooth.